# OBJ model texturing issue: material does not work while assigning scrolling texture, how can I fix it?

Tags: aframe

Please, help me with my problem =(
I need assign scrolling texture material to obj model. How i can do it?

When i try to set material for a primitive box - this material work good

When i try to set material for a obj mode - this material not working, and model keep white

Please, help me :(
This my code, for scrolling texture

```
<script>
          function startPlaying(event) {
          //document.getElementById("scene").style.display = "block";
          //document.getElementById("videoTex").play();
          //event.target.style.display="none";
          }

          AFRAME.registerComponent("slideshow", {
        init: function () {
            // load the .pngs
            let loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
            this.pngArray = [];
            let anim1_frames = 20; // total frames
            for (var i = 0; i < anim1_frames; i++) {
                if (i < 10) {
                    //i = '0' + i; // add 0 in front of single digit frames
                }
                this.pngArray.push(loader.load('https://urginsan.github.io/webTesting/sequence1/TextureAtlas_' + i + '.png')); // push TextureLoader loaded with img to array
            };
            
            this.el.addEventListener('model-loaded', e => {
            let mesh = this.el.getObject3D('mesh');
            this.material = mesh.material;

            var i = 0;
            this.id = setInterval(e => {
                if (i >= this.pngArray.length) i = 0;
                this.material.map = this.pngArray[i++];
                this.material.needsUpdate = true;
            }, 1000 / 25);
            })// play at 25fps
        },
        remove: function () {
            clearInterval(this.id);
            // free the memory
            for (let i = 0; i < this.pngArray.length; i++) {
                this.pngArray[i].dispose();
            }
        }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: You want to change it with a mouse scroll?

Comment: No, i want to change this automatic, like a sprite animation.